# How to read multiple values from JSON object array in php?

Tags: php, html, arrays, json, if-statement

```
<?php      
    $output['toggle_multi_tiles']=$_POST['toggle_multi_tiles'];  

    $fp = fopen('../feeds/ptp-ess_landing.json', 'w');
    fwrite($fp, json_encode($output));
    fclose($fp);
    logActivity();

    if(file_exists('../feeds/ptp-ess_landing.json')){
    $data = json_decode(file_get_contents('../feeds/ptp-ess_landing.json'));
    }
?>
```

I have a **JSON** as shown below:

```
{"toggle_multi_tiles":["0","1","2","3"]}
```

What I want is from the **php code below** I want it to print as:

```
<p>Hello World<p>
<p>Logical World<p>
<p>Good Morning </p>
<p>Good Evening</p>
```

It should not print `<p>Good Day</p>`

> Php code:

```
<?php if ($data->{"toggle_multi_status"} == 1) {
    if(in_array("0", $data->toggle_multi_tiles)) { ?>     
        <p>Hello World<p>
    <?php } else if (in_array("1", $data->toggle_multi_tiles)) { ?>
        <p>Logical World<p>
    <?php } else if(in_array("2", $data->toggle_multi_tiles)) { ?>
        <p> Good Morning </p>
    <?php } else if(in_array("3", $data->toggle_multi_tiles)) { ?>
        <p>Good Evening</p>
    <?php }
    <?php } else if(in_array("4", $data->toggle_multi_tiles)) { ?>
        <p>Good Day</p>
    <?php }
}
?>
```

`$data->toggle_multi_tiles` is reading from JSON.

Comment: Is this the real code? It has syntax error.

Comment: Syntax error where ?

Comment: `<?php }` you open the php tag but don't close

Comment: `"4"` its not defined condition should start from 0 not from `1, 0-3` , not `1-4`

Comment: I understand, I guess.. But what's wrong?

Comment: The above php is printing only `<p>Hello World</p>` and this condition `($data->{"toggle_multi_status"} == 1` is true.

Comment: Using `else if` will mean it will only do 1 output.

Comment: It's because you have `else if`. Just remove the `else` and should work.

Comment: @FelippeDuarte are you sure ?

Answer (score 1):

Why not just build an output array with keys that match the numbers in the response that you want to check:

```
$data   = json_decode(file_get_contents('../feeds/ptp-ess_landing.json'));
$output = ['Hello World','Logical World','Good Morning','Good Evening','Good Day'];

foreach($data->toggle_multi_tiles as $value) {
    echo isset($output[$value]) ? "<p>{$output[$value]}</p>" : "";
}
```

In this example `$output` starts at `0`, to use different numbers:

```
$output = [2=>'Hello World',
           4=>'Logical World',
           6=>'Good Morning',
           8=>'Good Evening','Good Day'];  //etc...
```

If you want to do totally different things then you can use a `switch` in the loop, either using the `$output` or not :

```
foreach($data->toggle_multi_tiles as $value) {
    switch($value) {
        case 0:
            //complex HTML
            break;
        case 1:
            //complex HTML
            break;
        case 2:
            //complex HTML
            break;
        case 3:
            //complex HTML
            break;
    }
}
```

Comment: Although its a right approach but the html code can be very complicated. I have used `<p>Good Morning</p>` just for example. It can be very complicated html code. It can be multiple divs and so on.

Comment: Do we need to use switch statement ?

Comment: This complex HTML will be similar for each number or totally different or what?  Might add to the question.